# pH of amphiprotic species

Tags: physical-chemistry

I was asked to find the pH of a diprotic species $\ce{BHA}$ where $B$ is the cation and $\ce{HA}$ is the anion given the first and second dissociation constant of acid $\ce{H_2A}$ and the base dissociation constant .

My book gives answer as $$\ce{[H+]}=\sqrt{K_{a_1} \left(\frac{K_w}{K_b}-K_{a_2}\right)}$$

I tried writing down the expression for the first and second dissociation constant and the base dissociation.Then I wrote mass balance as

$$\ce{[HA-]_{initial}=[HA-] + [H2A] + [A^2-]}$$

However I couldn't proceed after this. Any ideas.

Comment: How many unknowns and how many equations do you have?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have found out one more equation as $$\ce{H+}=[A^{2-}]-[HA^-]$$ However there are more unknowns and I couldn't solve them

Comment: My question was by no means rhetorical: how many unknowns and how many equations do you have?

Comment: You may have more luck breaking it down into the individual, sequential ionizations.   Keeping an the actual chemistry in mind is always useful.  As an aside, of the initial concentration is large enough, you can often disregard the contribution of the second ionization to the total pH of the solution.